# Paint circle method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find a way to draw a circle using JavaScript and redraw it while erasing the old circle.

i got this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>


  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 15;

  drawCircle(centerX,centerY,radius);

  drawCircle(150,150,25);


  function drawCircle(centerX,centerY,radius)
  {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
  };


</script>
```

The problem is that this two methods draw two circles instead of drawing one instead of the other.

I am beginner in JS would appreciate help on making better way of drawing and erasing the circle

Thanks

Comment: How about add color parameter your function?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Do you want a button that draws one circle and then another button that draw the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 15;

  function drawCircle(centerX,centerY,radius)
  {
    // Erase context
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
  };

  drawCircle(centerX,centerY,radius);

  drawCircle(150,150,25);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a circle from the canvas you will have to draw a circle (same position; same size) but this time with the color of the canvas background.

```
drawCircle(150,150,25,'black');
// ...
drawCircle(150,150,25,'white'); // removes previous circle if the canvas was white colored
```

If you want to erase everything from the canvas before drawing something new you can just execute this

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```